# Drawing shapes, text and images with moving and scaling in WPF

Tags: wpf, drawing

I'm trying to draw simple map in WPF. I need to draw shapes, text and images. It also should be possible to use mouse to move around and zoom in and out.

Right now, I have combination of Canvas + Geometry + Transforms to draw shapes, but I don't know how to add text and images.

I already tried various combination of Canvas/Grid and Layout/Render transform. Biggest problem is adding text and images, because transformations are in geometries.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you're currently putting Path objects (with transformed Geometries) into a Canvas. For adding text and images you could easily add [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) and [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) objects to the same Canvas and apply your transformations to their RenderTransform property.

A completely different approach would be to use WPF low-level rendering, provided by the [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingvisual.aspx) class. You may start at [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748373.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that my transformation have scale. So TextBlock and Image ends up rendered bigger. I don't want this.

Comment: Then use another transformation, that only has translation and rotation.